# Python: Making optional arguments as default

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to use the function with same arguments everytime so that I don't have to specify the optional argument.

For example,

in pickle.dump, https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump
instead of the default value of protocol to be 0, I would like it to be 1.

Hence, `pickle.dump(obj,file)` will evaluate as `pickle.dump(obj,file,1)` and not as `pickle.dump(obj,file,0)`

Comment: Just define your own function that calls `pickle.dump` with the arguments you want.

Comment: Yes, that is a fix, But is it not possible to change the default behaviour of the function itself inside the script ?

Comment: Define the function and reassign maybe: `json.dump = customized_dump`

Comment: Technically you "can" change the default behavior of pickle.dump() however...  You shouldn't, if you make changes to a library you will have to redo the changes everytime that library updates.

Comment: @Harold: But why do you care?  Just call your own function instead of `pickle.dump` and you're fine.  As Bioto says, you definitely do not want to change the behavior of `pickle.dump` for any code but your own.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is for

```
import pickle
import functools
mypickle = functools.partial(pickle.dump, protocol=1)
with open('data.dat', 'w') as f:
    mypickle(1, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your own `customized_dump` function that passes your desired default parameter to `json.dump`

```
def customized_dump(data, buffer, protocol = 1): return json.dump(data, buffer, protocol)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't actually write code like this, but it is possible to override the default arguments defined by a function.

```
import pickle

# Previous value was (None,)
pickle.dump.__defaults__ = (1,)

with open('foo.pkl', 'wb') as fh:
    # Should use protocol 1
    pickle.dump({'foo': 'bar'}, fh)
```

The values in `__defaults__` are assigned from right to left for unspecified positional parameters to a function call. For instance:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return 2 * a + b

foo.__defaults__ = (3,)   # Result of def foo(a, b=3)
foo(2)  # 2 * 2 + 3
foo.__defaults__ = (3, 6) # Result of def foo(a=3, b=6)
foo(2)  # 2 * 2 + 6
foo()   # 2 * 3 + 6
```

(Note that this won't work for built-in functions or other types without a `__default__` attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the old function and replace it with your own version that calls upon the previous. Personally, I would not recommend this, but it's your call.

```
import pickle
from functools import wraps

olddump = pickle.dump

@wraps(olddump)
def newdump(obj, file, protocol=1):
    olddump(obj, file, protocol)

pickle.dump = newdump
```

Now `pickle.dump` will use a default value of 1. If you are using this for pickle, perhaps it would be best to instantiate a `Pickler` object with a file and protocol and then make subsequent `dump()` calls to it? For example,

```
import pickle

with open("data.dat", "w") as f:
    p = pickle.Pickler(f, 1)
    p.dump([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    p.dump("abcdefg")
```